# + operator and strings

Tags: java, string, operator-keyword

I'm just starting out in AP Comp sci in high school and I stumbled across a question regarding the + operator in strings

Why does 
`System.out.println ("number" + 6 + 4 * 5)`
result in number620

whereas

```
String s = "crunch";
int a = 3, b = 1;
System.out.print(s + a + b);
System.out.print(b + a + s);
```

result in `crunch314crunch`?

Thanks

Comment: + is the concatenation operator you have to use the addition operator inside the () to differ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on [It's precedence order](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/11precedence/)

> When two operators share an operand the operator with the higher precedence goes first. For example, 1 + 2 * 3 is treated as 1 + (2 * 3), whereas 1 * 2 + 3 is treated as (1 * 2) + 3 **since multiplication has a higher precedence than addition** (+).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do any Math into `System.out.println`, wrap it with braces, because Java sees String at 1st place.

Try `System.out.println ("number" + (6 + 4 * 5))`.

For 2nd example use: `System.out.print(s + (a + b));`

in this case you have sum of `a` and `b`.

but in `System.out.print(b + a + s);` `b` and `a` stay at the 1st place. Compiler does `a+b` 1st and after add String, you don't need braces

Answer (score 0):

"*" has a higher operator precedence than "+", this means the expression "4 * 5" is calculated before the String concatenation happens.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Answer (score 0):

It has something to do with the operator precedence:

First, 4 * 5 = 20

Second, "number" is concatenated with 6, which is further concatenated with 20.

Answer (score 0):

On your first example, since you used a multiplicative operator, 4 is being multiplied to 5 before concatenated to other string. 
For the second example, you started with 2 integer before the String which will be calculated first before concatenated to a String.

Answer (score 0):

> Why does System.out.println ("number" + 6 + 4 * 5) result in number620

Because, * has higher precedence than +, so the result is `number620`.

> String s = "crunch"; int a = 3, b = 1; System.out.print(s + a + b);
>   System.out.println(b + a + s); result in crunch314crunch?

Here, + is used as operator overloading not as binary operation. So, '+' do concat operation, not sum operation. So, the result is `crunch314crunch`.

Answer (score 0):

It's about two things:

- operator precedence
- string concatenation vs addition

The `+` has the following rules:

```
int + int => int
int + string => String 
String + int => String 
String + String => String
```

That is, as soon as a `String` is involved, `+` means concatenation.

Operators with the same precedence are evaluated left to right. Therefore

```
String + int + int => String + int => String
```

but

```
int + int + String => int + String => String
```

The first case uses concatenation only, whereas the second uses addition in the first step.

---

In your first example, `*` has higher precedence than `+`, so the multiplication is performed first.

```
String + int * int => String + int => String
```

Answer (score 0):

### It's all about operator precedence and their associativity.

Your first example: **"number" + 6 + 4 * 5**

Acc. to operator precedence `*` is calculated first, so it becomes **"number" + 6 + 20**

Now, Associativity for `+` is Left -> Right (L->R), so + becomes a concatenation operator cause it is used with `String`, so the expression becomes **"number6" + 20**, and then **"number620"**

(Actually the `int` are converted to `String` before concatenation)

Similarly, your 2nd example:

Only `+` operator and start execution from L->R

**"crunch" + 3 + 1** = "crunch3" + 1 = "crunch31"

**1 + 3 + "crunch"** = 4 + "crunch" = "4crunch"

Answer (score 0):

According to your question and answer

explanation is

```
1.
  A)System.out.println ("number" + 6 + 4 * 5);
  B)System.out.println ("number6" + 4 * 5);
  C)System.out.println ("number6" + 20);
  D)System.out.println ("number620");
```

And it prints output like

```
number620
```

And Second one is

```
2.
  A)System.out.print("crunch" + 3 + 1);
    System.out.print(1 + 3 + "crunch");
  B)System.out.print("crunch3" + 1);
    System.out.print(4 + "crunch");
  C)System.out.print("crunch31");
    System.out.print("4crunch");
```

And it prints output with in a line, why because you have used `print()` statement

```
crunch314crunch
```